# XSLT add number to substring

Tags: xslt

Could you please help how to add or sub integer from substring? Here below my substring, and want to add this value to 5

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($values/smt1/smt2[position()=1]/smt3 , 12, 2)"/>
```

Lets say above value is 3, how to make it 8? And can i use also mod opetator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$string` contains `"abc03de"`, then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 4, 2)"/>
```

returns "`03`".

---

In XSLT 1.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 4, 2) + 5"/>
```

to get a result of `8`.

---

In XSLT 2.0+ you need to expressly convert the resulting substring to a number before it can be used in a numerical operation, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(substring($string, 4, 2)) + 5"/>
```